# What is a "pod"? Something like an apartment, perhaps?

Tags: meaning

Usage example (from the movie [*Automata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_%28film%29) (2014) starring Antonio Banderas):

> Have you ever considered how fortunate you are? You got a good job. You live in a great **pod**. You have health insurance that allows you and Rachel to have a beautiful baby girl. It's a good life, Jacq.

Audio version: http://vocaroo.com/i/s0OByLEq8o8o (in case you're not sure if he really says "pod")

What do you think it is? My guess is he's talking about a type of apartment, but I'm not really sure about that. And I couldn't find any definitions for this word online.

Comment: I have three reasons it could be "a small flock of birds.": 1. It exists in a [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pod)! 2. It could be followed by a sentence that supports it (as it's a way of writing) and, the meaning of the latter sentence implies that so. 3. It could be simile. It would be nice if you quoted the source.

Comment: What is the source?

Comment: I've never seen this. It could be a typo for 'pad'; it could be slang for apartment, derived possibly from the 60s concept of a 'living pod'; or it could be a neologism from science fiction, with a similar derivation.

Comment: A "pod" is a very small apartment.  Or, at least, very small by U.S. standards. [In round numbers ( < ~40 square meters or < ~450 sf ) ]  They are also called "apodments," although that is technically a trademarked brand name.  A google search for "pod apartment" will turn up dozens of stories about how these are the next big thing in cities like San Francisco or Seattle, where the rental market is out of control, and young people just need a place to sober up between partying and going to their tech jobs.

Comment: It is a *futuristic* apartment-style dwelling, emphasis on compactness.

Comment: Given the added Sci-Fi context, I agree with @Tromano.

Comment: Haven't seen it.  Are you sure he isn't saying __pad__, a common slang term for an impressively attractive apartment?

Comment: I double-checked. The guy in the movie clearly says "pod" with an "o". I'll make an audio recording and include it in my post.

Comment: @MARamezani - by exactly the same reasoning, it could be small flock of whales, and would make just as much sense.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast My hunch turns out not to be true. But, if it was, how likely is it for a [reputable] writer to "simile" people to birds, rather than whales? :)

Comment: @MARamezani - The word you want is "liken", not "simile" (which is a noun, not a verb). On a lighter note, why not whales? They are far smarter than birds, bear their young live, and have been known to sink at least one ship. Sounds more like people to me.

Comment: That's scientific merit, @WhatRoughBeast, not "literature" merit. Let's not chat in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[a**Pod**ment](http://apodment.com/) is a registered trademark of Calhoun Properties, LLC.  Calhoun builds and operates apodments in the city of Seattle.

An "apodment" is a separately rentable bedroom-bathroom suite in an apartment, with use of the apartment's kitchen, in a building full of such units.  A typical apodment has 150 - 275 square feet of private space, not including shared kitchens, hallways, stairs, and entries.

A [typical apodment building](http://seattletimes.com/html/localnews/2020845443_apodmentscitycouncilxml.html) includes 4 - 8 apartments.  Each apartment includes a kitchen, and is therefore a legal "dwelling unit" (according to typical American laws).  Each apartment also typically includes 6 - 8 apodments.  (The number is usually based on the local zoning law's limit on the number of "unrelated people" who can live in the same "dwelling unit".)

Some typical advantages of [apodments](http://apodment.com/), for the people who live in them:

- The monthly rent includes the cost of water, sewer, garbage removal, electricity, and broadband Internet service.  (Telephone service and cable TV service are available, but not included in the monthly rent.)
- A janitorial service cleans the shared kitchen once per week; this cost is included in the monthly rent.
- Flexible leases (Initially three months, then month-to-month).
- Each unit includes a refrigerator, a sink for washing dishes, and cupboards.  (These features greatly reduce the hassle of sharing a kitchen.)
- Individually lockable rooms.  (This is more secure than most "roommate" arrangements for splitting the cost of an apartment.)
- Each apodment has its own lease.  (This eliminates many of the hassles, arguments, and legal risks of typical "roommate" arrangements.)
- They are usually located within walking distance of stores and bus lines.
- They are usually located within walking distance of parks, coffee shops, bars, libraries, bookstores, and other social venues.
- So far, Seattle apodments have a reputation for attracting safe, law-abiding residents.

Some typical disadvantages of apodments, for the people who live in them:

- The buildings usually have very few parking spaces.  Apodments can be a good option for people who do not own cars, but are probably not a good option for people who do own cars.
- Shared kitchens.
- It might be illegal for more than one person to live in an apodment.  (If it is illegal, it is probably just a zoning law violation, not a crime.)

Here are some typical advantages of apodments, for the people who build them.  These advantages result in cost savings that are passed on to the residents:

- Parking requirements are typically based on the number of kitchens, not the number of apodments.  Thus, a group of 30 apodments might have only 2 or 4 parking spaces.  (A group of 30 tiny apartments might have 15 - 30 parking spaces.)  Providing lots of parking is expensive, and often results in ugly buildings.
- Apodments are typically built in cities with lots of requirements, design reviews, and delays for building large apartment buildings.  Apodments are typically designed to avoid the design reviews and delays, because they have so few legal "dwelling units".